# Sort Files into Array by Line Content

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have is an array of markdown files like this:

```
$mdfiles = glob("content/*.txt", GLOB_NOSORT);
```

I want to sort the files by a certain line inside each of them.

An example file is:

```
File
====
line-one:
date: [number-to-sort]
```

The array of files is then sorted by [number-to-sort] in each file, which can be accessed by:

```
$file_array = file($mdfiles[*], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
substr($file_array[*], 6);
```

Finally I would like to strip each `content/` and `.md` from the array key values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looked a lot smaller in my mind, but the resulting code is just three lines :)

```
$files = glob('content/*.txt', GLOB_NOSORT);
// sort the file array by date; see below
usort($files, 'by_file_date');
// strip the filename
$files = array_map('strip_filename', $files);
```

The `'by_file_date'` function is declared later and basically uses the `get_date` function internally to perform the date "pulling" from the files. I've used `preg_match` based on the form you've shown to find the date value; I've assumed that `date` is an integer (i.e. sequence of digits). If not, let me know.

```
// pull date value from the file
// @todo this function can be optimized by keeping a static array of
//   files that have already been processed
function get_date($f)
{
    // match the date portion; i'm assuming it's an integer number
    if (preg_match('/^date:\s*(\d+)/', file_get_contents($f), $matches)) {
        return (int)$matches[1];
    }
    return 0;
}

function by_file_date($a, $b)
{
    // sort by date ASC
    return get_date($a) - get_date($b);
}
```

Finally, you need to strip the filename; Assuming you just want the file name and not the directory:

```
function strip_filename($f)
{
    // strip the directory portion
    return basename($f);
}
```

Not sure where `.md` came from, so you have to let me know on that one :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
foreach( $mdfiles as $file ) {
    $file_array = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $order = substr( $file_array[0], 6 ); // get 6th character till the end of the first line
    $files[$order] = basename( $file, '.md' );
}
ksort($files); // might need this depending on how youre using the array
```

You had most of it.  Just needed to put the file in a new array and basename the dir and ext off

Comment: I dont think `$mdfiles[*]` or `$file_array[*]` is a valid syntax.

Comment: @Jack - I was assuming the $date would be unique.  If it isnt use `$files[][$order]` and `array_multisort()`.